# Bundle display name for a free app, that can be upgraded to the full version

Tags: ios, icons

I already have an app on the Appstore, let's say it's called 'MyApp', and I'm currently now creating a free/lite version called 'MyApp Free'.

MyApp Free will have an in-app upgrade purchase option, which will make it fully functional like MyApp.

The problem is, because we can't dynamically change the bundle display name, it will be continued to be called 'MyApp Free', with the icon on the users device, after a user has upgraded it. which is undesirable.

So can I get away with setting the bundle display name to just be MyApp, even though it's called MyApp Free on the Appstore. Also consider that I already have an app out there called MyApp.

I've searched lots of posts but need clarity on whether Apple will let me get away with leaving out the 'Free' bit for the display name.

Comment: The displayed name is determined by the meta-data you enter within iTunesConnect - no need for any correlation with your bundle name.

Comment: So you think Apple would be fine with the app being called 'MyApp Free' on the Appstore, and just 'MyApp' on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Apple don't really care so much with the Bindle Display Name. I have exactly the same setup as yours and it's on the AppStore. (Both of my apps' Bundle display name is MyApp even one's Bundle ID is MyApp and the other's is MyAppLite, with the same upgrade path possibility with in-app purchase from Lite to Full)

WARNING!

BUT BE CAREFUL not to change the product name in the Build Settings!!! Just change the Bundle display name in the plist file deleting ${PRODUCT_NAME} to the desired new Bundle display name. If you accidentally change the product name this could change the Bundle Name too as this use the same ${PRODUCT_NAME} by default.

If you don't care enough this will cause that the users couldn't upgrade as the app name in their devices will be different! This could cause a confused situation on the AppStore as there will be users with different app name as the new users meantime download your new app with the new Bundle/App name so you have to make a painful decision with the new upgrade which user groups do you like to support as both is not possible.